# can I use "str".equals(obj) with toString implementation?

Tags: java

```
String s="test";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("test");

System.out.println(s); //prints test
System.out.println(sb); //prints test

s.equals(sb); -> false
```

can anyone explain why

Comment: Because `sb` is not a `String`

Comment: maybe `s.equals(sb.toString())` ?

Comment: sb.toString() works, but printing sb results to "test" too. why is it returning false.

Comment: Because the method is calling `obj.toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is because `String` object is different from `StringBuilder` object.**

What you *may* want is :

```
s.equals(sb.toString())
```

Here's what `String` class's `equals` method *looks like*:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) { // this condition is false for StringBuilder objects
           // some logic here
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Taken from [openjdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java).

As you can see the `equals` method would `return false` due to following condition :

```
if (anObject instanceof String)
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the help!! it means I've passed the StringBuilder reference to the .equals() method and not the String, which also clarifies what @Abhisek said that System.out.println(obj); automatically calls .toString() method behind the scenes

Answer (score 2):

`s` is a `String`, and `sb` is a `StringBuffer`.  They are not the same object, so by default, they cannot be equivalent.

It also doesn't help matters that `StringBuffer` [doesn't override `Object.equals`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuilder.java), so a `StringBuilder` object will [only ever be equivalent to its same instance](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L149).

Comment: I take it, you meant "not the same class". Because equals is made for comparing different objects for logical equality. And your argument about the override is moot since equals is called on String.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is not `StringBuffer`.   But yes `StringBuilder` does not override equals method.

Answer (score 1):

And just to throw light on why printing both of them do the same thing, in the background: When you call `System.out.println` on a StringBuilder Object, it automatically calls the `toString` method on the object for you.

So, you give it your StringBuilder object like this: `System.out.println(sb);` but it effectively (and automatically) converts it to `System.out.println(sb.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a `String`, while `sb` is a `StringBuilder`, and thus they are not equal. If you want to check if their string representations (`toString()`) are equal, you'd have to do so directly:

```
System.out.println(s.equals(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that `StringBuilder` does not overrides `equals` and `hashcode` methods. Hence the `equals` method uses default objet identity comparison. As such 2 `StringBuilder` instances such `sb1` and `sb2` are equals if and only if `sb1==sb2` is true.

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = sb1;

if(sb1.equals(sb2){
  //they are equals
}
```

Hence, could not satisfies String `equals` method *SYMMETRIC* contract, when you perform `sb.equals(s)` test.